# Overloading factory function for rvalue and lvalue reference - efficient initializing

Tags: c++, templates

Consider following piece of code:

```
struct b{
//slow to copy, fast to move data
};

template<class T>
struct c{
    c(T &&, b &&){}
    c(T &&, const b &){}
    //do I have to provide both? 
};

template<class T>
auto
make_c(T &&t, b &&_){
    return c<T>(std::forward<T>(t), std::move(_));
}

template<class T>
auto
make_c(T &&t, const b &_){
    return c<T>(std::forward<T>(t), _);
}
//do I have to make both make_c overloads?
```

As the comments say - is it necessary to make both rvalue and lvalue make_ functions/constructors or is there a way to avoid code duplication. I must say I feel somehow uncomfortable with copying most of the function code just removing move function.

PS: This is a synthetic example - adding additional template argument(s) is impossible due to msvc compiler issues with `operator |` overloading.

Comment: My approach would depend on what happens to the referenced object inside the final function: here, what is done with the `b` in the constructors of `c`.  The current answer of "nothing" isn't very realistic, and suggests just getting rid of the argument or changing it to some tag type.  Presumably in a real scenario you would need to copy or move it into some member or container, or print it, or something?

Comment: @aschepler In most cases I would like to copy object/object's reference inside the created object

Comment: It all depends on whether `b` contains anything that benefits from being moved. Right now it doesn't, and neither would `struct b { int value; };`

Comment: @BoPersson Let's assume it has something worth moving. I know I did not state it in explicit manner but this is the most important assumption of this question. I clarified it now in the code sample

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid copying the code, you'll need to use a *forward reference*. These, however, are based on a template argument deduction. That is, you *could* use something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename B>
auto
make_c(T&& t, B&& _){
    return c<T>(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<B>(_));
}
```

While it may work to use manual overloading doing so doesn't quite work when you got multiple arguments requiring different treatment for lvalue and rvalue arguments: the number of overloads needed grows exponentially with the number of such arguments.